# Delete and return in a single verb?

Tags: language-agnostic, naming

Imagine a function that deletes a cookie and returns its value.

What would you call it if you have to use a single verb?

I called it `clear` but I'm not very fond of the name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds similar to `Pop`, except `Pop` typically acts on the last element in a collection. Perhaps `Extract` could be a suitable name?

Comment: Ouch. There goes my convention that List.Delete removes an item from the list and frees it, while List.Extract removes the item from the list and returns it, but certainly does not free it. Having an extract that deletes something, feels very disconcerting. I'd simply call the method Delete or DeleteCookie. The fact that the cookie is deleted seems far more important than that the method also happens to return the last value...

Answer (score 3):

In the Ruby [doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html) for `hsh.delete(key)`, their doc is:

*"Deletes and returns a key-value pair from hsh whose key is equal to key. If the key is not found, returns the default value."*

So `deleteCookie` would probably be acceptable, the key is to just **document the behavior** properly.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like this:

```
public String GetAndDeleteCookie(String cookieName); // C#
function getAndDeleteCookie(cookieName); // JavaScript
get_and_delete_cookie(cookieName); // php (forget exact syntax)
```